# Regex how to get everything apart from the first character

Tags: java, regex

This is my string

```
username=john903?fullname=john&smith
```

This is my regex so far

```
=([^?]*)
```

I am trying to capture "john903"

However this currently returns "=john903"

Comment: It is available in captured group #1

Comment: I want it as regex

Comment: Your question says you're trying to get "john903" and that you're trying to get "=john903". Which are you trying to get?

Comment: The regex you have posted captures "john903"

Comment: @j_k_g_99904 show us the code you use to capture the match.  It should only be a little tweak to get match group #1 instead of the whole matched string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript:** (Originally the question was tagged with Javascript)

The regex you have currently captures the value you want, but returns an array. The match without the equal sign is in the second element of the array:

```
var str = "username=john903?fullname=john&smith".match(/=([^?]*)/)[1] 
//str is now "john903"
```

**Java:** (OP commented they are in fact using Java)

```
String line = "username=john903?fullname=john&smith";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=([^?]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: Your question is tagged with Javascript. You should delete this and start over.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake from me

Comment: added java solution @j_k_g_99904

Comment: Can you tell me how you did that so I can try and find how to go about doing another one that bring back "john&smith" from that string I provided

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize positive lookbehind to achieve this. [Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

and here's a fitting regex

```
(?<==)([^?]*)
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work when I tried it

Comment: That's because JS regex doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @Amy tell me how to do it then since you know this haha

Comment: @jomin_george94 Look at the link I pasted in the comments below the question.

Comment: Well I did, if I could understand from it I wouldn't be asking you would I ?

Comment: ... okay then, what part of it didn't you understand?  The first answer is very straightforward and is doing *exactly* what you're wanting to do, just with a different regex.

Comment: @j_k_g_99904 I think you need to improve your question

Comment: You only include the tag 'java' (which was javascript earlier) and don't mention it in the question itself

Comment: I edited your answer solely so I could reverse my downvote (because OP tagged the question wrong)